# javascript web print. print a logo in the header of every page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

My trouble is I don't know how many pages it has when printing.
I have used the following CSS:

```
@media print {
    .barcode{
        position: fixed;
    }
}
```

So that the image appears in each page when printing. but on the second page or third page the image will overlap the content of the page as the screenshot.
[image: Barcode is overlapping data cells in table]

Comment: did you face similar problem. or has a solution.any help will be appreciate.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you want the barcode on every page without overlapping any content?

Comment: Do you have any solution to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

HTML

```
<div class='barcode'><!-- Barcode content --></div>
```

CSS

```
.barcode { display:none; }

@media print {
  .barcode  { display: block; position: fixed; top: -20px; height: 50px; }
}
```

The div needs to be positioned fixed in order to appear on every printed page. You can try adjusting the top property to position and move it above the content.

Comment: Hi Joey, thanks for your solution. but i am afraid that it cannot make sure that the barcode can be display on every page.

Comment: After some more research, i adjusted my answer.

Comment: unfortunately not working. the header of the printed page will block off the barcode.

Answer (score 1):

After reconsidering this, a much better solution would be to generate a PDF version of the page for printing.  Then you'll have much more control.  There are numerous PDF libraries out there for all server languages.

Comment: i also think so. at last we abandon the attempts to implement it with web page.

Comment: I'm glad you found my suggestion helpful.  Please upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to control this directly.  What you can try to do is regularly force page breaks and apply a height to that spacer div.  For example:

```
@media all
{
  div.page-break  { display:none; }
}

@media print
{
  div.page-break  { display:block; height: 100px; page-break-before:always; }
}
```

This will only work,  though, if you place enough `<div class="page-break"></div>`s in your page such that one appears before every natural page break would occur.

Reference: http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks

Comment: hi Rohler, thanks for your reply. but i am afraid it cannot apply to my situation. the content of my page is populated with the data out of database. I don't know how many entries will be retrieved when printing. so I don't know which place the page break div should be put into.

Comment: After every N entries (e.g. every 20 entries) add the break.  Experiment to see what works.

Comment: ok will try. thanks. :( there are a few section on the page. each section has variable entries.

Comment: probably like you said, no way to control it directly. thanks. we might try to find some third component to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak english, sorry. I solved similar issue following instruction on this page : http://thewebthought.blogspot.com/2011/10/html-css-header-and-footer-elements-for.html

Comment: thanks, i will also try it. but seems I cannot see anything there. may be it is forbidden by my company.